# Display password from PostgreSQL database using web.py form

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, web.py

I am playing around with PostgreSQL and web.py and I have noticed that if I have a username and password in a database and given that the password may contain special characters that are members of `string.printable`, then when I want to print the queried password to the browser through a web.py template, something goes wrong with the character escaping and the password doesn't want to display. Instead the browser offers to download a text file (with no file extension) containing the password.

In my Python file:

```python
class login:
    ...
    def POST(self):
        ...
        cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM tbl WHERE username = %s", (f['username'].value, ))
        realpassword = cursor.fetchone()
        realpassword = realpassword[0]
        ...
        return realpassword
```

The password appears correctly in the text file that downloads, but how do I display the password as text on the webpage?

Comment: I hope that you are not really going to store passwords as plain text in your database.

Comment: Yes I am, just for the purposes of illustrating this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `string.printable` includes both vertical-tab `\x0b` and form-feed `\x0c`, neither of which are friends to browsers. Browsers assume they're receiving a file and offer to download it.

(string.printable isn't the same as ASCII.)

Instead of returning the raw `realpassword`, return  `repr(realpassword)`. Built-in `repr()` returns a "string containing a printable representation...", escaping control characters.

```
>>> import string
>>> print string.printable[-20:]
=>?@[\]^_`{|}~  



>>> print repr(string.printable[-20:])
'=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```